# Separate Effects Superpowered

Tags: xcode, audio, buffer, objective-c++

I'm working with the [SuperpoweredSDK](http://www.superpowered.com). The SDK comes with an example called SuperpoweredCrossExample which shows off a few of the DJ-esque features. I'm trying to modify it to allow fx (such as filters, rolls, and flanger) to be applied to one player at a time instead of both simultaneously.

I've attempted in the code below to have a different buffer for each player and then merge them using the SuperpoweredStereoMixer. Although this seems to work for many others in sample code I've found, for me it continues to to crash on the "mixer" line. Any help would be very much appreciated. I've been spinning on this for the last few weeks.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h"
#import "SuperpoweredFilter.h"
#import "SuperpoweredRoll.h"
#import "SuperpoweredFlanger.h"
#import "SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO.h"
#import "SuperpoweredSimple.h"
#import "SuperpoweredMixer.h"
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <pthread.h>

#define HEADROOM_DECIBEL 3.0f
static const float headroom = powf(10.0f, -HEADROOM_DECIBEL * 0.025);

/*
 This is a .mm file, meaning it's Objective-C++.
 You can perfectly mix it with Objective-C or Swift, until you keep the member variables and C++ related includes here.
 Yes, the header file (.h) isn't the only place for member variables.
 */
@implementation ViewController {
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer *playerA, *playerB;
    SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO *output;
    SuperpoweredRoll *roll;
    SuperpoweredFilter *filter;
    SuperpoweredFlanger *flanger;
    SuperpoweredStereoMixer *mixer;
    unsigned char activeFx;
    float *stereoBufferA, *stereoBufferB, crossValue, volA, volB;
    unsigned int lastSamplerate;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
}

void playerEventCallbackA(void *clientData, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent event, void *value) {
    if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess) {
        ViewController *self = (__bridge ViewController *)clientData;
        self->playerA->setBpm(126.0f);
        self->playerA->setFirstBeatMs(353);
        self->playerA->setPosition(self->playerA->firstBeatMs, false, false);
    };
}

void playerEventCallbackB(void *clientData, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent event, void *value) {
    if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess) {
        ViewController *self = (__bridge ViewController *)clientData;
        self->playerB->setBpm(123.0f);
        self->playerB->setFirstBeatMs(40);
        self->playerB->setPosition(self->playerB->firstBeatMs, false, false);
    };
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    lastSamplerate = activeFx = 0;
    crossValue = volB = 0.0f;
    volA = 1.0f * headroom;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); // This will keep our player volumes and playback states in sync.
    if (posix_memalign((void **)&stereoBufferA, 16, 4096 + 128) != 0) abort(); // Allocating memory, aligned to 16.
    if (posix_memalign((void **)&stereoBufferB, 16, 4096 + 128) != 0) abort(); // Allocating memory, aligned to 16.

    playerA = new SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer((__bridge void *)self, playerEventCallbackA, 44100, 0);
    playerA->open([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lycka" ofType:@"mp3"] fileSystemRepresentation]);
    playerB = new SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer((__bridge void *)self, playerEventCallbackB, 44100, 0);
    playerB->open([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nuyorica" ofType:@"m4a"] fileSystemRepresentation]);

    playerA->syncMode = playerB->syncMode = SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerSyncMode_TempoAndBeat;

    roll = new SuperpoweredRoll(44100);
    filter = new SuperpoweredFilter(SuperpoweredFilter_Resonant_Lowpass, 44100);
    flanger = new SuperpoweredFlanger(44100);

    output = [[SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO alloc] initWithDelegate:(id<SuperpoweredIOSAudioIODelegate>)self preferredBufferSize:12 preferredMinimumSamplerate:44100 audioSessionCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback channels:2];
    [output start];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete playerA;
    delete playerB;
    free(stereoBufferA);
    free(stereoBufferB);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [output release];
    [super dealloc];
#endif
}

- (void)interruptionStarted {}
- (void)recordPermissionRefused {}

- (void)interruptionEnded { // If a player plays Apple Lossless audio files, then we need this. Otherwise unnecessary.
    playerA->onMediaserverInterrupt();
    playerB->onMediaserverInterrupt();
}

// This is where the Superpowered magic happens.
- (bool)audioProcessingCallback:(float **)buffers inputChannels:(unsigned int)inputChannels outputChannels:(unsigned int)outputChannels numberOfSamples:(unsigned int)numberOfSamples samplerate:(unsigned int)samplerate hostTime:(UInt64)hostTime {
    if (samplerate != lastSamplerate) { // Has samplerate changed?
        lastSamplerate = samplerate;
        playerA->setSamplerate(samplerate);
        playerB->setSamplerate(samplerate);
        roll->setSamplerate(samplerate);
        filter->setSamplerate(samplerate);
        flanger->setSamplerate(samplerate);
    };

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    bool masterIsA = (crossValue <= 0.5f);
    float masterBpm = masterIsA ? playerA->currentBpm : playerB->currentBpm; // Players will sync to this tempo.
    double msElapsedSinceLastBeatA = playerA->msElapsedSinceLastBeat; // When playerB needs it, playerA has already stepped this value, so save it now.

    bool silence = !playerA->process(stereoBufferA, false, numberOfSamples, volA, masterBpm, playerB->msElapsedSinceLastBeat);
    if (playerB->process(stereoBufferB, !silence, numberOfSamples, volB, masterBpm, msElapsedSinceLastBeatA)) silence = false;

    roll->bpm = flanger->bpm = masterBpm; // Syncing fx is one line.

    if (roll->process(silence ? NULL : stereoBufferA, stereoBufferA, numberOfSamples) && silence) silence = false;
    if (!silence) {
        filter->process(stereoBufferB, stereoBufferB, numberOfSamples);
        flanger->process(stereoBufferB, stereoBufferB, numberOfSamples);
    };

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    float *mixerInputs[4] = { stereoBufferA, stereoBufferB, NULL, NULL };
    float mixerInputLevels[8] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    float mixerOutputLevels[2] = { 1.0f, 1.0f };

    if (!silence) mixer->process(mixerInputs, buffers, mixerInputLevels, mixerOutputLevels, NULL, NULL, numberOfSamples);

    /*if (!silence) SuperpoweredDeInterleave(stereoBuffer, buffers[0], buffers[1], numberOfSamples); // The stereoBuffer is ready now, let's put the finished audio into the requested buffers.*/
    return !silence;
}

- (IBAction)onPlayPause:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (playerA->playing) {
        playerA->pause();
        playerB->pause();
    } else {
        bool masterIsA = (crossValue <= 0.5f);
        playerA->play(!masterIsA);
        playerB->play(masterIsA);
    };
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    button.selected = playerA->playing;
}

- (IBAction)onCrossFader:(id)sender {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    crossValue = ((UISlider *)sender).value;
    if (crossValue < 0.01f) {
        volA = 1.0f * headroom;
        volB = 0.0f;
    } else if (crossValue > 0.99f) {
        volA = 0.0f;
        volB = 1.0f * headroom;
    } else { // constant power curve
        volA = cosf(M_PI_2 * crossValue) * headroom;
        volB = cosf(M_PI_2 * (1.0f - crossValue)) * headroom;
    };
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

static inline float floatToFrequency(float value) {
    static const float min = logf(20.0f) / logf(10.0f);
    static const float max = logf(20000.0f) / logf(10.0f);
    static const float range = max - min;
    return powf(10.0f, value * range + min);
}

- (IBAction)onFxSelect:(id)sender {
    activeFx = ((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex;
}

- (IBAction)onFxValue:(id)sender {
    float value = ((UISlider *)sender).value;
    switch (activeFx) {
        case 1:
            filter->setResonantParameters(floatToFrequency(1.0f - value), 0.1f);
            filter->enable(true);
            flanger->enable(false);
            roll->enable(false);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (value > 0.8f) roll->beats = 0.0625f;
            else if (value > 0.6f) roll->beats = 0.125f;
            else if (value > 0.4f) roll->beats = 0.25f;
            else if (value > 0.2f) roll->beats = 0.5f;
            else roll->beats = 1.0f;
            roll->enable(true);
            filter->enable(false);
            flanger->enable(false);
            break;
        default:
            flanger->setWet(value);
            flanger->enable(true);
            filter->enable(false);
            roll->enable(false);
    };
}

- (IBAction)onFxOff:(id)sender {
    filter->enable(false);
    roll->enable(false);
    flanger->enable(false);
}

@end
```

Comment: Figured this out. I didn't initialize the mixer in the `viewDidLoad`: `mixer = new SuperpoweredStereoMixer(44100)`